# Get Region,State,PostCode separately from Contact address android

Tags: android, performance, android-contentprovider, android-contacts, android-contentresolver

I am facing a problem here fetching the address from device contacts. The Contacts app varies with different android devices. For example, as far as i saw the contact app in lenovo has separated fields to enter street,region,postalcode,etc., but the contacts app in my nexus7 and moto x only has a single field as address.
In my app I have separate textviews to show region, state and postcode. I have used the following code in onActivityResult.

```
if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
    Uri contactData = intent.getData();
    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(contactData, null, null, null, null);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        //to get full address
        //String address = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.FORMATTED_ADDRESS));
        String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String Street = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.STREET));
        String City = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CITY));
        String State = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.COUNTRY));
        String Zipcode = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POSTCODE));
        String District = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.REGION));

        System.out.print("name----" + name);
        System.out.print("Street----" + Street);
        System.out.print("City----" + City);
        System.out.print("State----" + State);
        System.out.print("Zipcode----" + Zipcode);
        System.out.print("District----" + District);
    }
}
```

The problem is i get the entire address in the String "Street". Example Street----123,ABC Street,xyz,123456. And the rest City,State,etc., are null. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Please post your SQLite database code also where you are storing it.@David

Comment: @CrazyAndroid I am not using any SQLite database code. The code that i have mentioned in the question is all that i have used to fetch the contact information.
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);      

intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_TYPE);

startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
This is the code that i have not mentioned.

Comment: @David Did you ever figure out a solution? I'm having the same issue. The Emulator's Contacts app only has one field for Address and everything is in there. When fetching that address it puts everything into `street` instead of separating them out. Thanks!

Comment: If you made a bug for this in the Android tracker, I would gladly Star it!